# Python unittest only running the first test and not the others

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to unittesting and trying to write tests for my code. In my test file, I have defined a test class and have two small tests for my file. However, when I run the file, only the first test runs.

Furthermore, the code I am importing the tests from, in separate functions than the one I am testing, is generating some plots, and those plots are being generated before the test is ran now.

Is there a way I could only run the tests, without having the file I'm importing the functions to be tested from run?

This is my code for the test class :

```
import unittest
from Expense import set_day_of_the_week
from Expense import add_two_expenses


class Heart_Rate_Model_Tests(unittest.TestCase):  

    def test_assign_initial_values(self):
        day_returned = set_day_of_the_week('Monday')
        self.assertEqual(day_return, 'Monday')


    def test_add_two_expense(self):
        food_expense = 12
        drink_expense = 5
        expense_sum = add_two_expense(food_expense, drink_expense)
        self.assertEqual(17, expense_sum) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The output obtained from the tests is :

```
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
OK
```

I have made changes to the first test to make it fail, and it does fail, therefore I'm sure it's the only test that is being ran, but changes made to it are seen

Comment: How are you running this and what's the output?

Comment: I am running this inside spyder, pressing the run button with the Expense_tests.py file selected. The output is simply ```Ran 1 test in 0.001s  OK ```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDBTsMwDD2Tr/BtqagmDYSQJu2EkLjsgrhbHnFZtDQpicvY15dU29pSIXyz3/N7z25Osg/@vuts3YQo0HorwkmUMlxBYkFDJwwVyp7xyHzQqVirm8jSRg/pTCNjUI4B@bthn1hTCbsJi@AWdkq9O0oJXpii4CsJ4zYYdviW3ZK@@i779okSF2sApSBX79BDmNfth0ebqZYcfpFrOenErspmcKk@7tmXDWz@vGCxDT7PFsWw1GssszxHef5syelRpYSRPs8zO3uWpArBXLGcZHU3ZozWHybQw4BcZpjaOs/nBlPF8rfKP7esHsupbpHfOny7Jut10XU/ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. I'm really not sure what the issue might be on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a new test file has fixed the issue. I'm still not sure what it was, I'm assuming it was a configuration error on my side, leaving this here if somebody in the future has a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who has the same problem in he future:
Check your compiling configurations. There might be just one specific test chosen when you click on 'run'.